# Get a portion of a string using a keyword regex in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, typescript

I have the following regex:

```
{thing:([^}]*)}
```

This matches '{thing:' and '}' exactly, and allows anything !} in the middle.

In C#, I was able to grab only the stuff in the middle with the following:

```
regex.Matches(stringToCheckForMatches).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value);
```

Is there an equivalent way to grab that middle stuff in TypeScript? Note also that stringToCheckForMatches can contain multiple instances of the {thing:} keyword (with any middle-stuff content).

For instance, I would want this:

```
'fooBar/{thing:hi}{thing:hello}'
```

To return (in an array/list preferably) just this:

```
hi
hello
```

**Alternatively**, if you cannot access .match captures in TypeScript (I am honestly not sure), is there a way to change the regex to something that captures only content after '{thing:' and before '}'? That would also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting by the regular expression results in `["fooBar/", "hi", "", "hello", ""]` :

```js
console.log( 'fooBar/{thing:hi}{thing:hello}'.split(/{thing:([^}]*)}/) );
```

and `filter` can be used to get the odd elements:

```js
console.log( 'fooBar/{thing:hi}{thing:hello}'.split(/{thing:([^}]*)}/).filter((_, i) => i & 1) );
```

or

```js
console.log( 'fooBar/{thing:hi}{thing:hello}'.split(/.*?{thing:(.*?)}.*?/).filter(Boolean) );
```

---

Alternative without regular expression:

```js
var str = 'fooBar/{thing:hi}{thing:hello}'

console.log( str.split('{thing:').slice(1).map(s => s.split('}')[0]) );
```